# Find the child nodes of a web page in javafx

Tags: java, html, dom, javafx

I want to find all nodes of a web page and get the absolute position of them, how can I do this via JavaFX?!
(in other words, I want to find the absolute position of each HTML tag when it is shown by a browser, how can i do this work via JavaFX or anything else?!)
I am using JavaFX 2-2.

For more details, please see the first two comments.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaFX? Is it run in the browser and you want to find position of some element on the same page? Or do you want to download some HTML page using JavaFX and calculate the position of an element?

Comment: tnx for answering, i want to do the second thing, i want to download some html page using javaFX and calculate the positon of an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need this: [JavaFX WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm).

Honestly, I have no idea how to use it, but looking at examples (on same page) I can see that it uses WebKit and allows you to query all the rendered elements.

Comment: Thanks, but I did all I could with webview methods and it didn't work. Any specific ideas?

Comment: Have you tried creating a WebEngine, loading a page into it, and then getting all element positions with some Javascript code: `webEngine.executeScript("some javascript code");` ? Sure, this is below optimal, but it's the easiest way I can see.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am going to do something like this